# Highcharts convert x-axis time to localtime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph that needs to show server up-time against the user's local time. UTC is not acceptable, as it needs to show the user's computer time.

Is there a way to convert the x-axis time to localtime? My current input looks something like this:

```
[UNIX_TIMESTAMP,1], [UNIX_TIMESTAMP, 2], ...
```

If not possible in highcharts, how would I convert the above in UTC to in the user's localtime (i.e., offset the UNIX_TIMESTAMP)?

Comment: Have you set `useUTC: false` ?

Comment: Would you mind posting your chartConfig code that you got working?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set useUTC to false in your global options:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC

Comment: This is now depracated. use time.useUTC in the chart options:  time: {
                useUTC: false
            }https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.useUTC

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get the local timezone offset from UTC in minutes in Javascript

```
var d = new Date();
var tzOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Once you have that you simply subtract that from your UNIX_TIMESTAMP and that's that.

Also, you may want to consider to not pass time values for every data point to Highcharts but instead use the [pointStart and pointInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/) series properties and then just pass the data.